# JSON deserialization with rootname

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I try to deserialize a JSON with an array I get the following error:

```
Root name 'countries' does not match expected ('Country[]') for type [array type, component type: [simple type, class com.diveconditions.domain.location.Country]]
```

I use the following code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

Country[] list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Country[].class);
```

And here my Country class

```
@JsonRootName(value = "countries")
public class Country
{
    @JsonProperty("countryName")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private LocalizedText name;
    @JsonProperty("countryIso2")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String twoCharacterIso;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UUID uuid;
}
```

This is how the json string looks like

```
    {
    "countries": [
        {
            "countryID": "2",
            "countryIso2": "AD",
            "countryName": "Andorra",
            "countryIso3": "AND",
            "is_created": "0",
            "is_updated": "0"
        },
        {
            "countryID": "3",
            "countryIso2": "AE",
            "countryName": "United Arab Emirates",
            "countryIso3": "ARE",
            "is_created": "0",
            "is_updated": ""
        }
    ],
    "downloadCompleted": 1,
    "success": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `class Country` doesn't specify all properties like: `countryiD`, `countryIso3`, `is_created`, `is_updated`

Comment: I think this is a good place to start with, since the error message is: `does not match expected ('Country[]')`.

Comment: I have set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false. So it should not fail due to unknown properties..